# Is there a way to have SSO using Atlassian for our external Django application?

Tags: python, django, oauth, jira, forge

We created a Forge app and we have an existing Django/Python application. Our forge app app has a connect button and when the user clicks it we want the user to automatically login with the credentials from Jira. Is there a way of possibly doing that?

We followed Django-OAuth-Toolkit documentation to build an OAuth 2.0 provider. We managed to get our access token using bash.

We followed the documentation on the Atlassian website for External OAuth 2.0 for Forge apps. But we could not get that working. We were expecting some type of response using the Google provider but kept getting errors. We aren't sure exactly what to do after this. The documentation vague.

Comment: please describe what you tried and what errors you were getting - as it is this is not answerable, because all anyone could do is link another general guide.